# can i change my url() to path() in urls.py

Tags: django

i use path() in urls.py, but i want to know what is the code if i change it to url()
i already try but i got error

this is my url.py code

```
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', views.VerificationView.as_view(), name="activate"),
path('request-reset-link', views.RequestPasswordResetEmail.as_view(), name="request-password"),
path('set-new-password/<uidb64>/<token>', views.CompletePasswordReset.as_view(), name="reset-user-password"),
```

Comment: What error you have got? How can we possibly help you without seeing the error traceback?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to? I would advise you not to use `url` as it's likely to be deprecated in future. If you insist on using it however, you can do it easily; all you need to do is import it, i.e.:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

Note the following from the documentation: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/)

> This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be
> deprecated in a future release.

So if you want to use a regular expression, you should use `re_path` instead.

Comment: i want use `templateddocs` but the django version is not compatible, do u have suggest ? what the alternate `templateddocs ` in django version 3.0.9

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: templateddocs use django version 1.8, and django version 1.8 cant use path

Comment: templateddocs says it supports django 1.8 and above. What error do you get when using `path`?

Comment: i got this `templateddocs 0.3.4 has requirement django<1.12,>=1.8, but you have django 3.0.9.`